# Determinar que tipo de triangulo es

Tags: linux, shell

Clear
echo -n ingresa el primer lado:
read l1
echo -n ingresa el segundo  lado:
read l2
echo -n ingresa el tercer lado:
read l3
If [ $l1 - eq $l2 - eq $l3 ]; then
           echo Es un triangulo equilatero

Comment: Que tal Yulissa, bienvenida... Por favor date una vuelta por [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta, tal como esta solo ganaras puntuaciones negativas y, en caso extremo, reportes... de paso podes darte un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio... mucha suerte...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Acá te completo lo que habias empezado, con comentarios para que veas que hace cada parte de la estructura de decision.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Ingrese la medida del primer lado' ;
read l1
echo 'Ingrese la medida del segundo lado' ;
read l2
echo 'Ingrese la medida del tercer lado' ;
read l3
#Aca verifico que los tres lados sean iguales
if [ $l1 -eq $l2 ] && [ $l2 -eq $l3 ]
then
    echo "El triangulo es Equilatero"
#Si no son los tres iguales, me fijo si al menos hay dos que coincidan
elif [ $l1 -eq $l2 ] ||  [ $l2 -eq $l3  ] || [ $l1 -eq $l3 ]
then     
    echo "El triangulo es Isosceles"
else
    #Si nada de eso sucede
    echo "El triangulo es Escaleno"
fi
```

Comment: Fue de mucha ayuda gracias